# POST previously checked boxes to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a table that is being created from a query like so:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {       
        $fields[] = $row['unit']; $fields[] = $row['reservation']; $fields[] = $row['guest'];
        $fields[] = $row['arrival']; $fields[] = $row['departure']; $fields[] = $row['balance'];
        $fields[] = $row['checked_in'];

        //rowid == id of table (the row corresponds to the row in the table)
        $rowid = $row['reservation'];

        $count = count($fields);

        //make checkboxes
        echo "<tr class='edit_tr' id='".$rowid."'>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$fields[1]."' name='checkins[]'/></td>"; 

        for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
        {
            echo "<td><span id='".$fields[1]."'>", ($j+1 == $count ? ($fields[$j] == 0 ? "Not Checked In" : "Checked In") : "".$fields[$j]."");
            echo "</span></td>"; 
        }

        echo "</tr>";

        //empty array
        $fields = "";
    }
```

I am `POST`ing all the checkboxes to a PHP file to `UPDATE` the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['checkins']))
{
    //open connection
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    //create WHERE clause for new checkins
    $where = " WHERE id =";
     foreach ($_POST['checkins'] as $id) {
        $where .= " $id OR id =";
    }

    //remove last 8 characters from WHERE clause
    $where = substr($where, 0, -8);

    echo $query = "UPDATE reservations
                    SET checked_in = CASE 
                    WHEN checked_in = 0 THEN 1 END
                    $where)";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

I know I can't `POST` the unchecked boxes but I need a way to tell the PHP file what has been unchecked. Here is what I've thought of so far:

1) Query the db for all `checked_in` = 1 where `checked_out` = 0 **(I am only displaying the rows where `checked_out` = 0 in the table)** and then set `checked_in` = 0 if the `id` is not in the `POST` results.

2) Send an ajax array to a different PHP file with a list of all the boxes that were previously checked and now aren't.

I am sure there are more but that's what comes to my mind. They all seem like workarounds, though. Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Comment: Your first option is actually the best bet but I have also seen people follow each checkbox element with a hidden element with the same name and a value of 0.  This will ensue that you always get a value posted.  The checked checkbox will override the hidden element.  It might also help if you include the id as part of the name.  name="checkins[$id]"

Comment: what benefit does including the `id` in the name have?

Comment: It lets you use values of 1 (for checked via a checkbox) and 0 (for hidden elements) to determine if a particular $id is checked or unchecked.  foreach ($_POST['checkins'] as $id => $value)